# Upgrading to RSpec 3 and following deprecation notice results in "undefined method 'allow'"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, cucumber, rspec3

Before upgrading RSpec, I had this block in my features/support/hooks.rb file:

```
After do
  begin
    Challenge.unstub(:current)
  rescue RSpec::Mocks::MockExpectationError
  end
end
```

After upgrading, I got this notice:

> DEPRECATION: Using `unstub` from rspec-mocks' old `:should` syntax without explicitly enabling the syntax is deprecated. Use `allow(...).to_receive(...).and_call_original` or explicitly enable `:should` instead. Called from /Users/grant/xx/features/support/hooks.rb:37:in `block in <top (required)>`.

Ok, sounds pretty straightforward.  I changed my code to this:

```
After do
  begin
    allow(Challenge).to receive(:current).and_call_original
  rescue RSpec::Mocks::MockExpectationError
  end
end
```

But now I'm getting:

> undefined method `allow` for `#<Cucumber::Rails::World:0x007facbed9f1d0> (NoMethodError)`

**Wat?  C'mon RSpec, I did exactly what you told me to do!**

Based on some Googling, I tried adding `require 'rspec/expectations'` to the top of this file.  It didn't do anything.

Can anyone fill me in on what I'm missing?

Comment: I guess you are missing `include RSpec::Matchers`. See here how to [include](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations#usage-outside-rspec-core). Hope it resolves your problem (yn).

Comment: Nope, didn't help.  Please note, this isn't happening in a class, but in features/support/hooks.rb, which just contains a bunch of before/after blocks.

Comment: Your changed code also isn't the same as the error message advised you - `to_receive` vs `to receive`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that what I'm doing is completely unnecessary, and that's probably why `allow` is not defined for the `After` context.

Rspec-mock stubs are removed after every example (in Rspec) or scenario (in cucumber), so unstubbing them in the `After` block is redundant and useless.

The whole `After` block that I'm trying to correct should instead simply be deleted.

([Special thanks to this post by Myron Marston on the Rspec Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/rspec/grant$20birchmeier/rspec/n0vDm30QNCg/FI9QCqGyw4MJ))

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your RSpec configuration doesn't enable the `allow` syntax. In your RSpec configuration file, probably `spec/spec_helper.rb` or `spec/rails_helper.rb`, do you have something like the following?

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.mock_with :rspec do |c|
    c.syntax = :should
  end
end
```

If so, see whether changing it to

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.mock_with :rspec do |c|
    c.syntax = [:should, :expect]
  end
end
```

fixes your problem. And then replace all uses of `should` with uses of `allow`, and upgrade other uses of the `:should` syntax, perhaps with [transpec](https://github.com/yujinakayama/transpec), and disable the `:should` syntax, and you'll be up to the minute.

Source: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/syntax-configuration